# Is JavaScript added and executed in parsing or in rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing, rendering

As far as I know, each webpage is created in a two stage process, initiated by a webserver request and ended in a webserver response:

1. **Parsing:** markup (Say HTML) is executed as is, or created by executing a "server-side" or "backend" programming language such as PHP.
2. **Rendering:** Styles (say CSS), are added upon the parsed structures.

Rendering could be done alongside parsing or after parsing; it depends on who the an web application was built.

### My problem

I don't know where does JavaScript come (usually), in parsing or rendering
<sub>I would assume **after** rendering but maybe some of it even before rendering was finished;</sub>

### My question

Is JavaScript added and executed in parsing or in rendering?

### Comment to `user:Niel` that might get deleted:

@Neil I have edited the question to example why I didn't forget anything in asking the question; I just didn't know that JavaScript can be loaded in all three stages of a webpages life cycle: Parsing, rendering and interacting, so it's not just "parsing or rendering" as I assumed originally. Reading from amon's answer and then your comment helped me to understand what I described about JavaScript specifically.

Comment: You're forgetting an essential step here.  The request is made to the server, and the server outputs or generates the actual html markdown.  Whatever language used to do this (PHP, JSP, etc.) is not relevant in terms of the client.  The client program (usually a browser) parses the entire document and before rendering, already loads or downloads any missing css, javascript, images, etc.  If the javascript is written plainly on the page, then it is simply parsed (no external files to download), otherwise it must ask the server also for the script to download.

Comment: @Neil browsers will start rendering before a document is completely loaded.

Comment: @Neil I have edited the question to example why I didn't forget anything in asking the question; I just didn't know that JavaScript can be loaded in all three stages of a webpages life cycle: Parsing, rendering and interacting, so it's not just "parsing or rendering" as I assumed originally. Reading from amon's answer and then your comment helped me to understand what I described about JavaScript specifically.

Comment: @JohnDoea Then it was my misunderstanding of the question, I apologize.

Comment: @Neil thank you, accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated, as JavaScript execution is interleaved with the normal lifecycle of the page.

First, the browser must parse the HTML code into the Document Object Model. When the parser encounters a script tag, the script is immediately parsed and executed.  The script can modify the HTML code via `document.write()`.

The browser will immediately try to render the DOM, even if the HTML code has not yet been fully parsed, for example if the full code hasn't yet been received. The browser will update the rendering if the DOM changes or as style information becomes available, for example when the correct font is loaded.

Unless proper care is taken, the user experience can be quite janky. Synchronous JavaScript is particularly problematic because its execution blocks further parsing – which might discover other resources that could have been loaded in parallel. So there are a couple of techniques to prevent blocking:

- use the async attribute for script tags so that the browser doesn't have to block until the script has been loaded & executed
- link and preload relevant resources as early as possible so that they can be downloaded in parallel
- avoid `document.write()`, instead perform DOM manipulation once the DOM is ready
- defer non-critical JS code until after the DOM is ready
- ideally, remove any JS code from the critical path, i.e. do not rely on client-side DOM manipulation. That means no React. Instead, use server-side templating. This may not be feasible for very dynamic applications like SPAs.

A note on terminology: “server side rendering” does not mean rendering a DOM with CSS, but serialising a DOM into HTML. So this is more like traditional template engines that are executed on the server, for example as a PHP page. For the client it is irrelevant how HTML is generated: they cannot tell the difference between static HTML files and dynamically rendered templates. In the end the browser just receives HTML code via HTTP which the browser has to parse & render.

Comment: Thanks amon. Please avoid this comment if you think it's unrelated (I think it will help me to make sure I understand but if you think I should ask a new question I will do so): If Async JS redunds the need to move sync JS to `<footer>` to prevent "blocking" (waiting for each JS resource in parsing) AND actually takes JS out of parsing to load it only in Rendering in a "First In First Out" way, why not **Always** use async and be done with it?

Comment: "its execution blocks further parsing" - usually the browser will keep parsing the data (and even recomputing CSS) in parallel with Javascript execution. It can't update the DOM from under Javascript's nose, but it can prepare the DOM resultant from the parsing and put it in place once Javascript is done running. It only has to discard that data if the Javascript pulls off some `document.write` type of nonsense. Best case, the Javascript merely sets up a ready handler and stops, in which case the rendering only pauses for the time it takes to retrieve the script from cache.

Comment: Not sure about the "don't modify DOM client-side" bit. The main bottleneck, as per my guess, is the network response time. GZip is really good at compressing HTML, but there may still be some savings. How much time is lost by having to render CSS after Javascript runs I'm not sure, but CPUs are getting fast these days...

Comment: Also, if you do server-side rendering on a server that's low on CPU resources (CPU hours cost hosting money), the time to do the rendering will become even more significant than the network time. And of course, all of that is moot if the main bottleneck is that it takes the database five seconds to answer the simplest of queries. I'm looking at you, Azure.

Comment: @JohnDvorak You do have some valid points: JS execution is not the problem, the problem is delayed discovery of resources that must be loaded. I don't quite buy the CPU resource argument though: if server resources were so precious we'd write backends in Rust not Ruby. Templates are generally not the problem.

Comment: @JohnDoea The async attribute is only available for script tags that link to an external script. If the script is inline it should be moved to the bottom of the HTML document, or just register a callback to run once the DOM has been fully loaded.

Comment: What is your source for "The browser will immediately try to render the DOM, even if the HTML code has not yet been fully parsed, for example if the full code hasn't yet been received. The browser will update the rendering if the DOM changes or as style information becomes available, for example when the correct font is loaded." Doesn't rendering happen after parsing is completed? any pointers on this?

Comment: @gaurav5430 I never bothered sourcing that because it seemed obvious, and can be easily reproduced by inserting some JavaScript code in a page in order to interrupt parsing (JS can modify the page source thus delays parsing). E.g. consider the URL `data:text/html,content before pause<script>alert("close to continue")</script> and more content.`. The Mozilla blog also contains some overviews of their Quantum engine, e.g. a post about [speculative parsing](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/building-the-dom-faster-speculative-parsing-async-defer-and-preload/).

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted and upvoted amon's answer and I start by suggesting fellow community members to upvote it also; so, the following is a summary of the core idea I extracted from both amon's answer and comments by `user:Neil` and `user: whatsisname`:

> JavaScript can be executed (loaded) in all three stages of a webpages
>   life cycle:
>
> - Parsing,
> - Rendering
> - Interaction (say, of a human with a website's webpage)
>
> Thus, it isn't necessarily just "in parsing" or "in rendering" or "in
>   both" as I (might) assumed originally.
>
> If and when JavaScript is executed depends solely on the architecture
>   of a web application (such as a website) in general, and on the
>   architecture of a web node (such as a webpage of a website) in
>   particular.